# X11 - multiple monitors visible as one monitor

Tags: x11, xorg, xrandr

I have three monitors which are configured in xorg.conf this way:

```
Option "metamodes" "DFP-4: 1920x1080+0+0, DFP-5: 1920x1080+0+1080, DFP-6: 1920x1080+0+2160"
```

Is it possible to set two or even three monitors as one monitor in xorg configuration ? For example:

```
DFP-4: 1920x1080+0+0,  DFP-5,DFP-6: 1920x2160+0+1080
```

I want to run google-chrome in a kiosk mode on two monitors, but the kiosk mode always maximize the window to the size of the screen which is configured in X11 so the only solution is change screens settings.

Comment: An extension to X11 called Xinerama can do that. See for example [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo)

Answer (score -1):

`xrandr` can help you with that. Run `xrandr` and see the names of connected monitor outputs. Then run this command.

`xrandr --output FirstMonitor --mode 1920x1080 --output SecondMonitor --mode 1920x1080 --right-of FirstMonitor --output ThirdMonitor --mode 1920x1080 --right-of SecondMonitor`

You just need to change the names of outputs with the names you get for those monitors when you run `xrandr` without arguments. They should be something like `eDP1 or DP1 or HDMI-1` change those values and run above mentioned command you can put it in your `.xinitrc` file if you are starting DE or WM from CLI.

Comment: This is wrong, at least for me!
Did not made "multiple monitors visible as one monitor" as OP asked. It simply puts each monitor side by side.
Chrome still maximize in a single monitor, not across all available monitors.
This is my experience in Ubuntu 18.04, using xorg and openbox.
Would like to know how to actually made one single virtual screen of e.g. 3840x1080